# How to maintain WCF services in production?

Tags: wcf

What is the proper way to push out WCF service updates? Right now we just use the file system publish method that deletes all existing files prior to publish. This has to be done at say 2am so we don't interrupt end users. However, what if we HAD to push an update out middle of the day?

Is this where wrapping ClientBase with timed retries comes in handy? Thus the client's call while we're deploying initially fails, but it will re-try and succeed a second or so later (in theory)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One question at a time, please. And you already answered your own first question.

Comment: Hi again, let me get your question. the problem is, that the client call could fail while you are depolying the new wcf service? And you want to solve this or what? Sry for my question, but I dont know what you mean eaxactly.

Comment: Yes, we have 1000+ users and fairly high activity, a few times we had to publish during the day and that causes the user to get an endpoint not found exception. Currently, if they were in the middle of saving a large order, the save fails and they have to go re-enter everything. What the proper way to deploy "live"? Or is this problem solved on the client proxy by re-trying?

Comment: Yes you can solve it on Client side. you can. I post an answer later, which can help you a lot in this topic.

Answer (score 0):

so you can inspect the Client.open method, or any business-method the client calls from the Service. Here you can for example, build a request channel (implements IRequestChannel) and a channelFactory to create a simple channel to the service, and then try to establish a Connection. If the service is not reachable an exeption is thrown. You can repeat this Kind of "probing" the service in a while Loop or something else. At the end, the clinets Open() Method or the busines method will wait until the service is reachable, and then it will continue. If the service is reachable you will jump out of the behavior and continue in business-code.

So the key is to implement a ClientBehavior for the Client, then in the validate-method build a ChannelFactory with a RequestChannel and try to connect to the service. This connection is somehow tried in a while Loop. If the connection will be accepted at the e.g. 4th time, the loop will be ended, the behavior closed and the busines-code will continue.

If you have any further question, feel free to ask me.